# margin top with percentage doesn't match the parent div

Tags: html, css

basically I'm trying to position an icon in the center of an inner div. In my code I have a div inside a div inside a div. I would like the to center text in the innermost div so I tried using margin-top: 50% Instead, the text went further past the halfway point. I thought the innermost div would find the halfway point in the parent div and position accordingly. Please explain why I am wrong. thx

```
    <html>
<body>
<div id="container" style="height:1000px;width:100%;background-color: green;position:absolute;">

    <div id="inner" style="height:50%; width:50%; background-color: black;margin-top:50%;display:inline-block;">
        <div id="inner" style="height:50%; width:50%; background-color: yellow"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I tried making html 100% high, but the divs still don't line up nicely. here's the js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/op8sdq0a/

Comment: thanks guys, I was using the above example as a simplification of this site I'm trying to make, I wanted to make the arrows in the middle of the photo gallery (the green div) on either side. Sorry if the earlier example presents a different problem than this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fqLmcnL3/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin-top:50%` means that the *top border* of the element will be at the vertical half, which doesn't center the element.

To center that element it's best to use relative positions and `display:block` for all elements, `top:50%`, `left: 50%` hich moves the upper left corner to the center of the parent, and in addition `transform:translate(-50%, -50%)`, which moves it back (up and left) by half of its own height and width.

In addition the parent element has to have a defined height (which in your case is true). Here is a fiddle with the complete code:

https://jsfiddle.net/49Lvzszj/1/

Comment: im curious as to why you used relative postioning in the inner divs as opposed to absolute positioning

Comment: absolute position would work as well in this case, but I prefer to use relative since that doesn't take the element out of the context of its parent, which can be an advantage for elements whose content can be dynamic, and when there are more than one children elements. BTW: I noticed there are TWO elements with IDs "inner" in your fiddle - that shouldn't be done - make those classes instead of IDs (an ID should be unique in a page).

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r5vsp9ek/11/).

```css
        * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .first {
          height: 500px;
          background-color: black;
          display: table-cell;
          width: 500px;
          text-align: center;
          vertical-align: middle;
        }
        
        .second {
          display: flex;
          justify-content: center;
          height: 300px;
          width: 300px;
          background-color: white;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }
        
        .third {
          align-self: center;
          height: 200px;
          width: 200px;
          background-color: green;
          padding: 25%;
        }
```

```html
<div class='first'>
  <div class='second'>
    <div class='third'>Text is hereby centered!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```